# Limit of singletons

Tags: limits

Let $a ∈\mathbb R$ and let ($x_n$ : $n ∈\mathbb N$) be a sequence of points in $\mathbb R$, all distinct from $a$, such that $\lim_{n→∞}x_n=a.$

Show that $\lim_{n→∞}\{x_n\}$ exists and is different from $\{a\}.$

1. I suppose that "a" is a point, so the sequence xn goes to a when n goes to infinity and that's ok by def.
2. How can the limit of singletons ( i suppose that {xn} means the single point of the sequence) exist and also be different from a?
3. I was thinking about using cauchy convergence, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: By showing that limsup and liminf are equal, so the lim exists?

Comment: What about saying that xn can be increasing or decreasing towards a. But if xn is increasing and those are points, x will never be infinitely often in the limsup so the latter is the empty set and also the liminf, so the lim exists and is the empty set. What about that?

Comment: That was my new conclusion. If x belongs to the limsup it means that it is infinitely often in the sequence but, since {x_n} are singleton, if it is in x1, it will not be in x2 in case of an increasing sequence, so it's empty. And since lim inf is contained in limsup, it empty too. So liminf==limsup==lim==empty.  I have no more idea

Comment: I read the post you sent, but I can't find anything helpful since in the statement it talks about increasing and decreasing sequences. Any hint?

Comment: Okay the point that (xn) may not be monotonic. It was a bit forced. I don't  know that to say on the sets of the singletons.

Comment: If xn→a and all xn's are ≠a, at a certain point and more precisaly at infinity, the x can't be a so it will not be there infinitely often so limsup is empty?

Comment: I'm trying, but I can't find anything else useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [definition of the limit of a sequence of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533566), let us prove that $\limsup_{n \to \infty}\{x_n\}=\varnothing$ (it will prove that $\lim_{n→∞}\{x_n\}=\varnothing$), i.e. let us prove (by contradiction) that no real number $x$ can belong to infinitely many $\{x_n\}$'s.

If $x$ was equal to $x_n$ for an infinity of indices $n$, the sequence $(x_n)$ would admit a constant subsequence $x_{n_k}=x$, so the limit $a=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ would also be a limit of that subsequence, i.e. we would have $a=x$. But then, $a$ would be equal to $x_n$ for some $n$ (even many: all the $n_k$'s), contrarily to the hypothesis.